# Laravel url() function in Docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-octane

I'm running Laravel with Octane with frankenPHP. It works fine but does not show images. I found that url() function in my views returns http://localhost:8002 which is docker address. I expect url() to return my domain name for example: http://example.com

In my docker-compose.yaml I have:

```
version: "3.9"
    services:
      app:
        image: "my_image:latest"
        entrypoint: php artisan octane:frankenphp
        restart: unless-stopped
        hostname: example.com
        ports:
          - "8002:8000"
```

My .env file:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=prod
APP_KEY=base64:api_key
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://example.com
```

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: probably you need to update the env variable `APP_URL`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post my .env file. APP_URL is http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `APP_URL` in your .env file

Change `APP_URL=http://localhost` to this `APP_URL=http://example.com`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post my .env file. APP_URL is http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I hadn't set X-Forwarded-For in my NGINX. Now it works.